# Why is not the condition *First1 == * First2 ?? (C++ STL includes function implement)

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I'm a student studying STL C++ and have a simple Question.

I was wondering while learning how to implement the includes function in the algorithm library. See this code
(this code from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes)

```
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2> 
bool includes(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2) {
    for (; first2 != last2; ++first1) {
        if (first1 == last1 || *first2 < *first1)
            return false;
        if ( !(*first1 < *first2) )
            ++first2;
    }
    return true;
}
```

There are questions in this section.

```
if ( !(*first1 < *first2) )
            ++first2;
```

This part appears as a code that determines whether `*first1` is equal to `*first2` to determine whether a given partial sequence is part of an ordered sequence. I think.

If so, `*first1 == * first2` seems enough, I wonder why `!(first1 < first2)`.

Are there any special reasons for this condition??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requiring equality is an unnecessarily strong condition; a [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) (which `<` [must be](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LessThanComparable)) is sufficient.

Note that `!(*first2 < *first1)` is implied by the previous condition's being false, so `first2` is incremented when `*first1` and `*first2` are equivalent according to the ordering.

Answer (score 5):

One of the *concepts* required by the type `InputIt1` is that it implements the `<` operator. (The other comparators `==`, `!=`, `<=`, `>=` and `>` can all be written in terms of `<` if you allow the expression to be negated with `!`, although formally the replacement of `==` is known as *equivalence*.)

The C++ standard library function therefore writes the condition check in terms of `<`.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LessThanComparable